# How can I create a CHECK constraint on a VARCHAR column in MSSQL specifying a valid set of characters that may appear in the data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, check-constraints

I have a VARCHAR(30) column in a Microsoft SQL database representing a username. I'd like to add a CHECK constraint that allows only a certain range of characters to be used: specifically, a-z, A-Z, underscore and dash. What expression must I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
create table t (
   a varchar(30) check (
      a like replicate('[a-zA-Z\_-]', len(a)) escape '\'));
```

If your collation is not case sensitive then you don't need both `[a-z]` and `[A-Z]`.

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE TABLE T 
(
 a VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE
    CHECK (a NOT LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z\_-]%' ESCAPE '\')
);
```